# Magento: Where is this "$_formatedOptionValue" being created?

Tags: function, magento, product

If, in magento you have a bundled product, and you have a few product options for it. On the shopping cart page, on the checkout page, and in other places, these options will be displayed using this code:

```
<?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?
```

This code can be found in many places, for example in ***/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml *** 
about line 43

Anybody knows where can I get the **behind** of this code "formatedOptionValue". I want to modify a bit the way the product options are being displayed and constructed. Please, if you know, can you point out the direction of where this function is being constructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `$_formatedOptionValue` will be assigned within the same template file where it's used.

In standard Magento this assigment will be done by calling `$this->getFormatedOptionValue()`, which in turn mostly maps to one of these two methods:

```
Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer::getFormatedOptionValue()
Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Item_Renderer_Default::getFormatedOptionValue()
```

Comment: Thanks Jürgen for the answer. I found it in the Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer::getFormatedOptionValue(). Do you know how can i remove the price that being showed for the product options?

Comment: Glad it helped^^; please vote/accept it to your liking. Regarding price removal: since this would be off-topic in this post, please just post a new question and tell us for which product type (simple, bundled, etc.) and using what template you want to remove prices from the output. Preferrably showing a sample product including its options, so we can see what kind of product you're talking about.